# What is the difference between Convert.ToBoolean(string) and Boolean.Parse(string)?

Tags: c#, parsing, boolean

What is the difference between the two methods

`Convert.ToBoolean()`

and

`Boolean.Parse()`?

Is there any reason to use one or the other?

Additionally, are there any other `type.Parse()` methods that I should watch out for?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 93, accepted):

`Convert.ToBoolean(string)` actually calls `bool.Parse()` anyway, so for non-null `string`s, there's no functional difference. (For null `string`s, `Convert.ToBoolean()` returns `false`, whereas `bool.Parse()` throws an `ArgumentNullException`.)

Given that fact, you should use `bool.Parse()` when you're certain that your input isn't null, since you save yourself one null check.

`Convert.ToBoolean()` of course has a number of other overloads that allow you to generate a `bool` from many other built-in types, whereas `Parse()` is for `string`s only.

In terms of type.Parse() methods you should look out for, all the built-in numeric types have `Parse()` as well as `TryParse()` methods. `DateTime` has those, as well as the additional `ParseExact()`/`TryParseExact()` methods, which allow you specify an expected format for the date.

Comment: Thanks for the details.  So, there is no difference in performance between the two, or you could say extremely small gains by using Boolean.Parse(string)?

Comment: @mbrownnyc You would get a very minor (likely imperceptible) gain by using `Parse()` *if you're certain the input isn't a null string*. If you're not sure, just use `ToBoolean()`, since it will do the check for you. And if you don't want a null string to result in false, then perform the check yourself, and then call `Parse()` if it's not null.

Answer (score 43):

Here is the short demo:

```
object ex1 = "True";
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBoolean(ex1)); // True
Console.WriteLine(bool.Parse(ex1.ToString())); // True

object ex2 = "true";
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBoolean(ex2)); // True
Console.WriteLine(bool.Parse(ex2.ToString())); // True

object ex3 = 1;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBoolean(ex3)); // True
Console.WriteLine(bool.Parse(ex3.ToString())); // Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException

object ex3 = "1";
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBoolean(ex3)); // An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred
Console.WriteLine(bool.Parse(ex3.ToString())); // Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException

object ex4 = "False";
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBoolean(ex4)); // False
Console.WriteLine(bool.Parse(ex4.ToString())); // False

object ex5 = "false";
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBoolean(ex5)); // False
Console.WriteLine(bool.Parse(ex5.ToString())); // False

object ex6 = 0;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBoolean(ex6)); // False
Console.WriteLine(bool.Parse(ex6.ToString())); // Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException

object ex7 = null;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBoolean(ex7)); // False
Console.WriteLine(bool.Parse(ex7.ToString())); // Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException
```

Note: There are also two properties of `bool` TrueString and FalseString, but be careful, because `bool.TrueString != "true"`, only `bool.TrueString == "True"`

```
Console.WriteLine(bool.TrueString); // True
Console.WriteLine(bool.FalseString); // False
```

Comment: `Convert.ToBoolean("1"); // Format Exception`

Comment: `Convert.ToBoolean("2");` will also return a truthy value. I know that booleans are sometimes referenced as 0 and 1, but you never know that someone mistypes something.

Answer (score 3):

`Boolean.Parse()` will convert a string representation of a logical boolean value to a boolean value. `Convert.ToBoolean()` has multiple [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toboolean.aspx) that will convert primitive types to their boolean equivalent.

Most, if not all, of the primitive types in C# have an associated *.Parse/Convert.To* method that serve the same purpose as `Boolean.Parse()/Convert.ToBoolean()`.