# how to convert a string to a bool

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have a `string` that can be either "0" or "1", and it is guaranteed that it won't be anything else.

So the question is: what's the best, simplest and most elegant way to convert this to a `bool`?

Comment: If any unexpected values can be in the input, consider to use TryParse (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329001/parse-to-boolean-or-check-string-value/18329085#18329085)

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Quite simple indeed:

```
bool b = str == "1";
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe how much I was over thinking this

Answer (score 85):

Ignoring the specific needs of this question, and while its never a good idea to cast a string to a bool, one way would be to use the [ToBoolean()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on the Convert class:

`bool val =  Convert.ToBoolean("true");`

or an extension method to do whatever weird mapping you're doing:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool ToBoolean(this string value)
    {
        switch (value.ToLower())
        {
            case  "true":
                return true;
            case "t":
                return true;
            case "1":
                return true;
            case "0":
                return false;
            case "false":
                return false;
            case "f":
                return false;
            default:
                throw new InvalidCastException("You can't cast that value to a bool!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Behavior of  Convert.ToBoolean shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031964/what-is-the-difference-between-convert-tobooleanstring-and-boolean-parsestrin/26202581#26202581

Comment: Feel [Boolean.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) is preferable when a lot of values need to be converted as it does not throw `FormatException` like [Convert.ToBoolean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 51):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but just to help other people. If you are trying to convert "true" or "false" strings to boolean:

Try Boolean.Parse

```
bool val = Boolean.Parse("true"); ==> true
bool val = Boolean.Parse("True"); ==> true
bool val = Boolean.Parse("TRUE"); ==> true
bool val = Boolean.Parse("False"); ==> false
bool val = Boolean.Parse("1"); ==> Exception!
bool val = Boolean.Parse("diffstring"); ==> Exception!
```

Comment: Needed it for a Powershell script reading some XML data and this is perfect!

Answer (score 20):

```
bool b = str.Equals("1")? true : false;
```

Or even better, as suggested in a comment below:

```
bool b = str.Equals("1");
```

Comment: I consider anything of the form `x ? true : false` humorous.

Comment: `bool b = str.Equals("1")`  Works fine and more intuitive at first glance.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Not so intuitive when your String `str` is Null and you want Null to resolve as False.

Answer (score 8):

I made something a little bit more extensible, Piggybacking on Mohammad Sepahvand's concept:

```
    public static bool ToBoolean(this string s)
    {
        string[] trueStrings = { "1", "y" , "yes" , "true" };
        string[] falseStrings = { "0", "n", "no", "false" };


        if (trueStrings.Contains(s, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return true;
        if (falseStrings.Contains(s, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return false;

        throw new InvalidCastException("only the following are supported for converting strings to boolean: " 
            + string.Join(",", trueStrings)
            + " and "
            + string.Join(",", falseStrings));
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I used the below code to convert a string to boolean.

```
Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(myString));
```

Comment: It is unnecessary to call Convert.ToInt32 if the only two possibilities are "1" and "0". If you are wanting to consider other cases, var isTrue = Convert.ToBoolean("true") == true && Convert.ToBoolean("1"); // Are both true.

Comment: Look at Mohammad Sepahvand answer Michael Freidgeim comment!

Answer (score 3):

Here's my attempt at the most forgiving string to bool conversion that is still useful, basically keying off only the first character.

```
public static class StringHelpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert string to boolean, in a forgiving way.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stringVal">String that should either be "True", "False", "Yes", "No", "T", "F", "Y", "N", "1", "0"</param>
    /// <returns>If the trimmed string is any of the legal values that can be construed as "true", it returns true; False otherwise;</returns>
    public static bool ToBoolFuzzy(this string stringVal)
    {
        string normalizedString = (stringVal?.Trim() ?? "false").ToLowerInvariant();
        bool result = (normalizedString.StartsWith("y") 
            || normalizedString.StartsWith("t")
            || normalizedString.StartsWith("1"));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    private static readonly ICollection<string> PositiveList = new Collection<string> { "Y", "Yes", "T", "True", "1", "OK" };

public static bool ToBoolean(this string input)
{
                return input != null && PositiveList.Any(λ => λ.Equals(input, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
public static bool ToBoolean(this string input)
        {
            //Account for a string that does not need to be processed
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                return false;

            return (input.Trim().ToLower() == "true") || (input.Trim() == "1");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I love extension methods and this is the one I use...

```
static class StringHelpers
{
    public static bool ToBoolean(this String input, out bool output)
    {
        //Set the default return value
        output = false;

        //Account for a string that does not need to be processed
        if (input == null || input.Length < 1)
            return false;

        if ((input.Trim().ToLower() == "true") || (input.Trim() == "1"))
            output = true;
        else if ((input.Trim().ToLower() == "false") || (input.Trim() == "0"))
            output = false;
        else
            return false;

        //Return success
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then to use it just do something like...

```
bool b;
bool myValue;
data = "1";
if (!data.ToBoolean(out b))
  throw new InvalidCastException("Could not cast to bool value from data '" + data + "'.");
else
  myValue = b;  //myValue is True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string sample = "";

bool myBool = Convert.ToBoolean(sample);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to test if a string is a valid Boolean without any thrown exceptions you can try this :

```
    string stringToBool1 = "true";
    string stringToBool2 = "1";
    bool value1;
    if(bool.TryParse(stringToBool1, out value1))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(stringToBool1 + " is Boolean");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(stringToBool1 + " is not Boolean");
    }
```

output`is Boolean`
and the output for stringToBool2 is : 'is not Boolean'