# How to handle the CheckBox in MouseClick events?

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have a Problem Guys, I hope you help me..

I want to display the selected data row to my textbox and checkbox and I having a Problem with the CheckBox and the error Cannot implicity convert type string to bool

I set my Checkbox to true or false after saving to the Database so it will show in my Datagridview only True or False not Checked and the Checkbox is the Option if it is undergo that Case...

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

```
    {
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            if (control is CheckBox)
                ((CheckBox)(control)).Checked = true;

        }

        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            if (control is CheckBox)
                ((CheckBox)(control)).Checked = false;
        }
    }
```

And in my Mouse Click Event

private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)

```
    {
        txtFam.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtName.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txtSevereheadache.Checked =dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtBlurringvision.Checked = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        txtAbdominal.Checked = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        txtSeverevomiting.Checked = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        txtBreathingdifficulty.Checked = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        txtConvulsion.Checked = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        txtEdema.Checked = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        txtVaricosities.Checked = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
        txtFeverchills.Checked = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
        txtPain.Checked = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[31].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: "and the Checkbox is the Option if it is undergo that Case" - what does this even mean? Please try formulating the whole question a little better, if you want people to read it and understand immediately, so they can answer.

Comment: @alterfox For example I'm a Patient then I have experiencing  Severe headache and Blurring of Vision.So the Staff will check the Severe headache and Blurring of Vision after saving, it will show in Datagridview True(Checked) and the others False(not Checked) When I click the Data in Datagridview I want the txtFam,txtName and Checkbox that checked will be show in my Form it means I want to Display the Selected row from my textbox and Checkboxes(will be checked if it is true) ..But I always got the Error Cannot implicity convert type string to bool and I dont know what does it means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to assign a string value to a boolean property. E.g.

```
txtSevereheadache.Checked = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

First use debug and see what is the type of `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value`, it is probably enough for you to cast `Value` to `bool`. So:

```
txtSevereheadache.Checked = (bool) dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value;
```

If for some reason `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value` is not of type `bool`, you should parse the string to boolean using `Boolean.Parse` method. See it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So, something like:

```
txtSevereheadache.Checked = Boolean.Parse(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
```

For differences between `Convert.ToBoolean(string)` and `Boolean.Parse(string)` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031964/what-is-the-difference-between-convert-tobooleanstring-and-boolean-parsestrin) thread.