# Why do Boolean.TryParse()] and Convert.ToBoolean() evaluate a string differently?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why do [Boolean.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Convert.ToBoolean()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2c31dd(v=vs.110).aspx) evaluate a string differently?

I understand how they end up evaluating differently:

1. Boolean.TryParse() will match (case insensitive) 'true' and 'false'.
2. Convert.ToBoolean() will match to a whole range of values (example demonstrated in Microsoft doco linked above) which I would consider more natural.

Its the reasoning behind the difference I dont understand.

There are a couple of discussions touching on this subject which don't seem to address this particular question.

Comment: Can you show some code to explain what exactly bother you ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031964/what-is-the-difference-between-convert-tobooleanstring-and-boolean-parsestrin

Comment: I don't agree regarding the duplicate. The answer selected clears up the question I had, which wasn't addressed in the linked issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in the method/class names.

**Convert** -> you already have some value, you `convert` it to another type. e.g. you have value `1` which can be converted to `true`.

**Parse** -> you have the value as a string and you `parse` it.

Comment: Thanks, this makes complete sense now : )